# is it feasible to add multiple index parameters in , Full text search API ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I need to run a *search* query like this :

```
SELECT from results WHERE owner=mike,john,tom ...etc
```

which should provide a concatenation of the items owned by those usernames. There may be about 100-200 usernames in the query.  Would be feasible to do this using the full text search API (I already use it for  keyword queries) using the usernames as filters (e.g. filter(1)=mike&filter(2)=john etc ) or I should try some kind of datastore *join* operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* construct a query like this:
`owner:mike OR owner:john OR owner:tom` etc., but this will not be efficient for a large number of possible owner values.
Instead, consider whether you could group the owners according to some application semantics (e.g. some owners in 'usergroup1', some in 'usergroup2', etc.), and then instead query for documents with e.g. `usergroup:usergroup1`.

Alternately, if you could assign each owner a numeric value (that makes sense for your application), you can use numeric comparators, e.g.  `owner_number < 10`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first query is MySQL query, right?
If field 'owner' have index in MySQL query then you could use following structure:

```
SELECT from results WHERE owner IN ('mike','john','tom')
```

I can't say too much about APP Engine, but certainly you need to use filters.

Comment: It's a GAE query .. however the query itself is not valid... I provided it as a "concept". @Amy U provided the correct query construction